# Ajax request speed issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I want to prevent from user sending requests from ajax too fast. I wrote a validation in controller as bellow.

```
def before_action
    if session[:expires_at].nil?
       logger.info "Operation is legal"
       session[:expires_at] = Time.current + 3.seconds
    elsif Time.current > session[:expires_at].to_time
       logger.info "Operation is legal"
       session[:expires_at] = Time.current + 3.seconds
    else
       logger.info "Error: Operation too fast"
       render json: { msg: "Operation too fast",res: "Err"}
       return
    end
    sleep 2 <-- The issue happends here
end
```

The sleep 2 seconds means my program excution time. If I remove sleep 2 seconds, everything works fine.The result would like below when I send the requests really fast.

```
-----------Logs-------------
Operation is legal
Error: Operation too fast
Error: Operation too fast
Error: Operation too fast
Error: Operation too fast
Error: Operation too fast
Operation is legal
Error: Operation too fast
Error: Operation too fast
Error: Operation too fast
----------------------------
```

But, if the second or more resquests been sended before the first one excutes finished. The result would be unexpected. If I add sleep 2 in the validation code.

```
-----------Logs-------------
Operation is legal
Operation is legal
Operation is legal
Error: Operation too fast
Error: Operation too fast
Error: Operation too fast
Error: Operation too fast
Operation is legal
Operation is legal
Error: Operation too fast
Error: Operation too fast
----------------------------
```

I am totally confused for this situation. Would the session value not being saved before the request finished? How should I fix this issue?

Comment: Try setting `request.session_options[:skip] = true`

Comment: It's not working for me. The results are always "Operation is legal" after added request.session_options[:skip] = true.

Comment: Did you add it before `if session[:expires_at].nil?` ?

Comment: Yes, I added at the first line of the function. Nvm I've solved it by using two steps validation. A validating request will be sent before user's request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it looks like the session variables will be stored later in processing a controller lifecycle? a workaround could be to use redis for this case?

you should find a way to be sure a variable you are using is persistent over more requests in parallel.

Comment: Yeah, session variables is stored after processing finished. I have no idea how to solve this issue.

Comment: I  guest I have to send a validating request first everytime before doing real request to see if the opreation is valid.

Comment: Two steps validation works fine for now. Thanks for the help.